# How to create a popup JPanel in a JFrame

Tags: java, popup, jpanel

I want help somebody. I want to create a JPanel that will popup when i click on a button, it must appear there where the button is clicked, and it must not affect other components. An example of that is a JDateChooser, when you click on that button, a calendar appears right there, but when you click anywhere else, that panel disappears. what i want is to put a list of names in that panel when it pops. It is similar to JPopupmenu except that when you click anywhere else it must disappear.

Comment: Well you have to provide what you have so far. You will have to use listeners to set the visibility to false to that jpanel I'd use an JInnerFrame or something that already had the JPanel, otherwise you will have to play with layered layouts.

Comment: why did'nt i think of a jinternal frame. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: JPopupMenu should be capable of providing this functionality

Comment: yes but how do i make it disappear when i click anywhere else?

Comment: It should do it by itself - from memory

Comment: it doesnt thats why i came here looking for a container that will disappear when you click somewhere

Comment: You can use the [WindowStateListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowStateListener.html) to handle all of this with whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're doing, but it seems to work just fine for me...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class ButtonPopup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonPopup();
    }

    public ButtonPopup() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
            DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
            model.addElement("Item 1");
            model.addElement("Item 2");
            model.addElement("Item 3");
            model.addElement("Item 4");
            model.addElement("Item 5");
            JList list = new JList(model);
            popup.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            popup.add(new JScrollPane(list));

            final JButton button = new JButton("Pop");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Dimension size = popup.getPreferredSize();
                    int x = (button.getWidth() - size.width) / 2;
                    int y = button.getHeight();
                    popup.show(button, x, y);
                }
            });

            list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    popup.setVisible(false);
                }
            });

            add(button);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }        
    }    
}
```